# iPad not showing programmatically-created UITable

Tags: ipad, uitableview

I have an iPad app that is not showing a table created programmatically. Where is the error or what is lacking in my code?

*ViewController.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface deleteViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
    UITableView *listTable;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *listTable;
//@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *listTable;



@end
```

*ViewController.m*

```
#import "deleteViewController.h"


@implementation deleteViewController
@synthesize listTable;



// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    listTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200) style:UITableViewStylePlain]; //changed THANKS!!, 

    listTable.delegate = self;
    listTable.dataSource = self;
    //listTable.allowsSelection = TRUE;
    [listTable reloadData];

    //listTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [listTable setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
    [self.view addSubview:listTable];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
     return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return 4;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];    
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    //cell.textLabel.text = [yourarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}


// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Doesn't the table have to show even with out data like an array to show? I had tested this with data from coredata and doesnt show it, so I did this bare-bones test first to show the uitable programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ended up following the  [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10)  duhh

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)

                                                      style:UITableViewStylePlain];

tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

tableView.delegate = self;

tableView.dataSource = self;

[tableView reloadData];


//self.view = tableView;

[self.view addSubview: tableView];

[tableView release];
```

and it shows fine !!, ;)

Comment: So it was because you added the `autoresizingMask` ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a `[[self view] setNeedsDisplay]` at the end of your `viewDidLoad` after you add the subView?

Comment: hi, tnx, no , did as you suggest and doesn't work either :(,,, I didn't have the setNeedsDisplay, shall I leave it any way?, what other thing can be?

Comment: you shouldn't need it and its safe to remove.  just wanted to see if it made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your frame looks way off.  You are adding that view as a subview to `self.view` try just using those dimensions instead or simply `CGRectMake(0,0,200,200)` to see if something shows.  If it does, then you've proven the current dimensions place it out of bounds and it's getting clipped.

Comment: hi, changed the CGRectMake(0,0,200,200) but still not showing,, what could it be? tnx